# is it possible to give restrictions to my own mobile app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, mobile, xcode7

For Example, I developed an e-Commerce(Selling Items) application in that there is an array it contains list of ITEMS, I have fixed no.r of items list, if client wants to add some more items in list then client should contact me for other changes without any third party hands. How to apply this rule for my own mobile application.?

Comment: please add what you've tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without seeing what you have down so far. There are several different ways to achieve what you describe. Each with pros and cons. If the changes can be applied programmatically, you may want to consider having your app interrogating a REST script on your server which takes the update, process it and send it back to the app. Any backend coding language would work (PHP, Perl, Node, etc.).
If the update requires your approval, you could have the script email you the update. Then you could record the update in a file on the server that the app load automatically at boot time presenting the updated content to the user.